# R execute script/function during installation

Tags: r, installation, rstudio, devtools

I am developing a package and I would like to know what is the best way to execute a script at installation time.

Essentially I want to make sure that third-party tools are installed,
retrieve them when I can and raise an error if some dependency is missing.

I am not referring only to R packages, but also to system-wide headers, fonts and similar dependencies.

What is the best strategy to follow in this case?

Comment: You can start by typing `library(X)` for each package `X` upon which your script is dependent.  If you don't have the package, you will see R attempting to download it.  In the case where it is already installed, it won't install it again.  I am unsure about "system-wide headers" and "fonts" though.

Comment: Before installing what? If you mean before starting R, you can create a `.Rprofile` file in your home directory and it will be executed any time at the startup of an R session.

Comment: @nicola sorry I wrote it in a rush, I think now the question is clearer.

Tim using library(X) in source code of packages is considered a bad practice and I want to avoid doing that. And I don't know if it is some option, but in my R instalaltion if I don't have package X, library(X) simply throws an error.

Comment: If your package depends on other R packages, just add them in the `Depends` section of the `DESCRIPTION` file of your package. For system-dependencies, just check section 1.2 of the manual: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Configure-and-cleanup

Comment: Have you looked at `devtools` source code? It searches for the build chain on installation. How is this issue rstudio related?

Comment: thanks but none of this is what I am talking about. During installation I would like some functions/external script to run. I need something like .onLoad and .onAttach but running only at installation time

Comment: @nicola section 1.2 and configure and configure.win are what I am looking for. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts to be run before installation should be placed in an executable file called `configure` (will be executed on Linux/Unix/Mac computers) or in a file called `configure.win` (will be executed in Windows computers).